PowerShell invoke-sql query returns differing results between PowerShell and SQL Server Management Studio
I have the following PowerShell code that searches a database and ultimately returns a cumulative filesize of the files listed within.
# Import the required modules
set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass
Import-Module -Name 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility'
Import-Module SqlServer

# FUNCTION: Search A Database
# The script runs a query and returns the results
function SQLQuery {

    param (
        [string]$instance,
        [string]$database,
        [string]$query
    )

    
    try {
        
        # Create a SQL connection with credentials
        $results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $instance -Database $database -Query $query -Verbose -TrustServerCertificate

        # Count the number of rows in the results
        $rowCount = $results.Count

        # Write to the log
        Write-Host "$instance $database | The query has completed and returned $rowCount result/s."

        #return the results
        return $results

    } 
    catch {

        # Write to the log
        Write-Host "$instance $database | Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"

        $results = $null
        return $results

    }

} # End FUNCTION SQLQuery

# Setup the database connection
$instance = "XXXXXXXXX"

$database = "XXXXXXX"

$query =    "SELECT
    document_dets.client_ref,
    document_dets.matter_suffix,
    archive.dept_code,
    document_dets.description,
    document_dets.doc_date,
    document_dets.file_name
FROM 
    document_dets
LEFT JOIN 
    archive 
ON archive.client_ref = document_dets.client_ref 
AND archive.matter_suffix = document_dets.matter_suffix 
WHERE
    doc_date >= Convert(datetime, '2023-05-01')
AND
    document_dets.description NOT LIKE 'NAP_%'
AND
    archive.file_status IN ('O', 'R')"

$SQLResults = SQLQuery -instance $instance -database $database -query $query
      
# Initialize a variable to store cumulative file size
$cumulativeFileSize = 0

foreach ($row in $SQLResults) {

    # Get the filename
    $filePath = $row["file_name"]

    try {
        # Retrieve the full file path of each item
        $fileDocument = Get-Item $filePath

        # Get the file size in bytes
        $fileSize = $fileDocument.Length

        # Add the file size to cumulative count
        $cumulativeFileSize += $fileSize
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "Unable to read the file $filePath to get file size. Error: $_"
    }


}

# Convert cumulative file size from bytes to gigabytes (GB)
$cumulativeFileSizeGB = $cumulativeFileSize / 1GB

# Output or log the cumulative file size in gigabytes (GB)
Write-Host "Cumulative file size: $cumulativeFileSizeGB GB"

Looking at the output, the Powershell script is returning 12557 results; however, when I run the same query in SQL Server Management Studio, I see 5054 rows returned.
I am at a loss now what to do...
I amended the query to look at just one record set using document_dets.client_ref = X allows me to look at just 10 rows of data. I thought I had it sorted as, for some reason the NOT LIKE part in the select didn't work so I started filtering the results within the Powershell itself, but when moving back up to the full set this returns the incorrect results.
Any pointers where this may be falling down?

Why do you LEFT JOIN to [dbo.]archive when the value of archive.file_status must have a non-NULL value? When would archive.file_status not have a non-NULL value if no row is found?

THE LEFT JOIN links the document_dets table to the archive table via the client_ref and matter_suffix.
There are some NULLS in the archive.file_status and I only want to return results that are either 'O' or 'R'

Convert(datetime, '2023-05-01') is sensitive to locale settings. Perhaps 20230501 will yield correct values (if you want first of may). archive.file_status IN ('O', 'R') makes LEFT JOIN against archive into INNER JOIN

That doesn't answer my question, @MatthewBarraud . If there is no row found then what do you expect archive.file_status IN ('O', 'R') to resolve to? You are requiring archive.file_status to have a non-NULL value, so why do you LEFT JOIN to it? it doesn't make sense to. Either the JOIN is wrong, or the WHERE.

There will always be an entry in the archive table for each document in the document_dets table

So then use JOIN (or long form INNER JOIN) not LEFT JOIN.

@Chalieface the results are still different between SSMS and PowerShell but both running the same query

Using the INNER JOIN still shows the discrepancy between SSMS and PowerShell. When running in SSMS I have 5054 rows and in PowerShell 12557

Whatever else you find, this is wrong: doc_date >= Convert(datetime, '2023-05-01'). It should be this:  doc_date >= '20230501'. For historical reasons, SQL Server is a little odd for correct date literals.

Also verify that doc_date isn't actually a string.

I also see you've done some work on comparing the two results different results, and the NOT LIKE expression has come under scrutiny. Can you confirm that if you remove the NOT LIKE expression from SSMS you get the same number of results as in Powershell?

@JoelCoehoom and siggemannen, you legends! The date string was causing the issue, although I have no idea why SSMS returned the number of results I expected. However, when running the SQL via PowerShell, this failed, and too many results were returned. When changing to 20230501 in Powershell, it matched.

Then, at a guess, one of Powershell or SSMS (probably SSMS) was including a cultural setting with the connection, while the other was not. The ISO-8601 unseparated date literal format will always be parsed the same way on SQL Server, and avoids these issues.

Because convert(datetime, '2023-05-01') (with the datetime type) only works like you'd expect when the session has set dateformat mdy; in effect. db<>fiddle.

@AlwaysLearning Or ymd

Check your connection flags/settings (ANSI NULLS etc.) in SSMS and PowerShell. They can have a dramatic impact on your query results.
